# Как добавить произвольный контейнер c определенным условием в php шаблон?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Возникла необходимость добавления произвольного контейнера в шаблон вывода материалов сайта. Ниже прилагаю схематические иллюстрации для наглядности и фрагмент кода. На данный момент элементы выводятся следующим образом: 
[image: фото 1]

**необходимо реализовать добавление кастомного контейнера, например после материала 6** следующим образом:

[image: фото 2]

Вот фрагмент кода который отвечает за вывод материалов:

```
<?php if(count($this->items)): ?> 
<div class="tagItemList">
    <?php foreach($this->items as $item): ?>
```

Через админ панель указывается количество отображаемых материалов на странице (в данном случае оно равно 12). Соответственно присутствует пагинация.

```
<!-- Pagination -->
<?php if($this->pagination->getPagesLinks()): ?>
<div class="k2Pagination">
    <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <?php/* echo $this->pagination->getPagesCounter();*/ ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы **custom DIV** отображался на позиции после материала 6 на каждой странице пагинации.
Спасибо!

Comment: не усложняйте. просто вставьте в массив исходных данных новый элемент на нужную позицию.

Comment: а как это сделать ?

Comment: Мне сложно понять ваши трудности. У этой задачи 2 варианта: 1) вариант в лоб (говнокод). прямо при выводе списка в хтмл заводим переменную счетчик (цикл for) и если $i==6, то вставляем свой блок вместо спискового и делаем $i-- 2) есть данные, есть метод отрисовки данных в таблицу, который может сделать таблицу из любого количества данных (элементарно). вводим понятие "тип элемента" и "рендер таблицы" просто проверяет "если такой тип элемента, то рисуем так". Изменяем массив данных по желанию, а рендер просто рисует

Comment: Я понимаю что это элементарно, но дело в том, что я не силен в данном вопросе. Поэтому постарался задать вопрос максимально развернуто, чтобы получить, насколько это возможно, развернутый ответ. Спасибо.